# Trying to re-iterate over a list to update values, from .jsp to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm doing a small training project which simulates a car dealer, and the administrator has a kind of "admin panel" from where he can manage a list of cars.

The problem comes when I try to update the status of a car (is it available, or not) based on the checkboxes, which get filled depending on a value from a database. So I would like to retrieve the values from the checkboxes in the .jsp page, in order to use them in the servlet and update them in the database if any checkbox has changed.

The .jsp part is implemented, but the problem comes with the servlet.

```
    <c:forEach var="car" items="${carList}">
<tr>
        <td>${car.brand}</td>

        <td>${car.year}</td>

        <td><input type="checkbox" name="isAvailable" 
        value="${car.available}"
        ${car.available == 'true' ? 'checked' : ''} /></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I've already tried to get the parameter and cast it, but I've already seen that it isn't the correct way... And also I've just created an array of string values from the checkboxes.

```
        String[] arrayIsAvailable = request.getParameterValues("isAvailable");
```

How can I get the list (its stored in the request) in this servlet in order to re-iterate over it updating values with the ones from the .jsp checkboxes?

Comment: Have you tried saving list in `session scope` instead of `request scope`

Comment: But I would still need to retrieve it also in the servlet, so I need convert the "string" that I'm getting from the getParameter method into a List. @NeerajJain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you are asking, however, assuming this call returns something:

```
String[] arrayIsAvailable = request.getParameterValues("isAvailable");
```

the issue you have is that you simply have a list of parameter values in no particular order and not associated with any particular car.

You need to bind the checkbox to a car in some way. If you update your JSP as below:

```
<c:forEach var="car" items="${carList}">
    <tr>
        <td>${car.brand}</td>
        <td>${car.year}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="isAvailable_${car.id}]" value="${car.available}" ${car.available == 'true' ? 'checked' : ''} /></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

your request will then contain a number of parameters like the below:

- isAvailable_1
- isAvailable_2 etc.

which will allow you to tie the values to specific cars doing something like the following in your Servlet:

```
for(Car car : cars){
    car.setAvailable(Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("isAvailable_" + car.getId()));
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! I was trying to parse all the values in the String[] array, in a for loop, to boolean, loosing the "false" values during the process. Thanks a lot! :)